# How to search from list by date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on this website and i wanted to search from the list with the date the specific hotel will be available on 
here's what i've tried

on my controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{

    IEnumerable<HotelAvailability> hotels = db.HotelAvailabilities.Include(c => c.Hotel);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
         hotels = db.HotelAvailabilities.Include(c => c.Hotel).Where(
                    s => s.RoomType.Contains(searchString) 
                        || s.AvailabilityDate.Equals(searchString) 
                        || s.Hotel.HotelName.Contains(searchString));

         return View(hotels);
     }
}
```

and on my view

```
<div class="box-tools pull-right">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "HotelAvailabilities", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 150px;">
            <input type="text" name="searchString" class="form-control input-sm pull-right" placeholder="Search">
             <div class="input-group-btn">
                 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
             </div>
         </div>
       }
</div>
```

Comment: What is `AvailabilityDate`'s type? Is it a Date field or a string?

Comment: DateTime field @adiga

Comment: `RoomType`, `AvailabilityDate` and `HotelName` can not be equal. You've used a value (`searchString`) for them.

Comment: Instead of using the same input for date, it will be better if you add a separate search field with a Datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your question how to search for a date: convert the search string into a `DateTime`.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) {

    DateTime searchDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(searchString, out searchDate)) {
        hotels = db.HotelAvailabilities.Include(c => c.Hotel)
            .Where(h => h.AvailabilityDate == searchDate); 
            // do not use .Equals() which can not be converted to SQL
    }

    return View(hotels);
}
```

A cleaner solution would be to provide an additional control (datepicker that returns DateTime) to let the user select the search date and process it in addition to the search words.

Concerning the search you have shown in your code example:

If you want to have everything in a single search string, you must split it into separate tokens for the query you have shown to work.

For example, if the User enters "Hilton 2016-09-01" you want to split this into "Hilton" and "2016-09-01" and then search using these tokens. I think this would be another question.